# How many times tennis majors champions played in the qualifiers round?

Tags: trivia, tennis, atp, wta, grand-slam

How many times a player who got in a grand slam through the qualifier round won the championship, and who are they?

Comment: Marginally related - according to Wikipedia, [Mark Edmondson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Edmondson) is the lowest ranked grand slam winner, winning [1976 Australian Open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1976_Australian_Open_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_Singles) with rank 212.

Comment: Perhaps it could be clarified whether you are interested only in singles or whether this question is also about other events. (I mean doubles, mixed doubles, wheelchair, juniors. Although I do not think I have seen qualifying for mixed doubles or wheelchair competition.) I'd guess that this did not happen in singles, but let's wait to see whether somebody can actually confirm this.

Comment: I'm interested in men and women singles. But if get no answer for a few days, I may change it up

Answer (score 3):

After winning [2021 US Open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2021_US_Open_%E2%80%93_Women%27s_Singles), [Emma Raducanu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emma_Raducanu) has [become the first person](https://sports.yahoo.com/emma-raducanu-becomes-first-qualifier-to-win-us-open-with-defeat-of-layla-fernandez-221233241.html) to win a Grand Slam tournament as a qualifier.

Answer (score 2):

No qualifier to one of the four major championships singles main draw has ever won that year's tournament. The farthest a qualifier has reached at a major is the semifinals with John McEnroe reaching the [1977 Wimbledon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1977_Wimbledon_Championships_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_Singles) Semifinals as a qualifier. Other qualifiers to reach grand slam semifinals are Filip Dewulf at the [1997 French Open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1997_French_Open_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_Singles) and Vladimir Voltchkov at the [2000 Wimbledon Championships](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2000_Wimbledon_Championships_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_Singles). A wild card though has won a major before with Goran Ivanišević winning the [2001 Wimbledon Championships](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2001_Wimbledon_Championships_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_Singles) as a wild card. 
On the women's side Alexandra Stevenson made the semis at [Wimbledon in 1999](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1999_Wimbledon_Championships_%E2%80%93_Women%27s_Singles) as a qualifier.