# Tennis men's or women's singles - most matches played to win a single tournament

Tags: trivia, tennis

What is the most tennis matches a man or woman has had to play to win a WTA or ATP tournament in the open era?. At the ASB Classic in Auckland, NZ, Bianca Andreescu is playing the final tomorrow in what will be her 8th match as this tourney (she had 3 x qualifying matches and 5 x main draw matches including the final). I know no qualifier has ever won a major so they will all be 7 matches. Has anyone ever had more than 8 matches?

Comment: Reaching semifinals at Grand Slam at the current format also means winning 8 matches (3 times in qualifying, 5 wins in the main draw). The answer to this question lists several players to achieve this: [How many times tennis majors champions played in the qualifiers round?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/15997) However, I am not sure where to check whether number of qualifying rounds was different in the past tournaments.

Comment: Thanks for that. Yeah I was particularly interested in winning the event but still interesting to know. Cheers

Comment: I will just mention that the [2019 WTA Media Guide](https://www.wtatennis.com/wta-media-guide) contains list of *Qualifiers/lucky losers to win a WTA singles title* and the 2017 ATP Media Guide lists *qualifiers champions since 2004*.

Answer (score 1):

**Won 9 matches at an ATP tournament**

- [Roberto Carretero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roberto_Carretero)
  won [1996 Hamburg Masters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1996_Panasonic_German_Open_%E2%80%93_Singles),
  winning three matches in qualification and six matches in the main
  draw. See: [ITF archive](https://www.itftennis.com/procircuit/tournaments/men's-tournament/info.aspx?tournamentid=1010001244), [1](https://uk.reuters.com/article/uk-tennis-us-salem/french-qualifier-herbert-maintains-marathon-run-idUKKCN0QX2KN20150829), [1a](http://web.archive.org/web/20190105091946/https://uk.reuters.com/article/uk-tennis-us-salem/french-qualifier-herbert-maintains-marathon-run-idUKKCN0QX2KN20150829) and [other sources](https://www.google.com/search?q=carretero+%22nine+matches%22+hamburg).

Comment: I am posting this as a CW answer, so that other users can add to it if they find similar results. (So far I only found one player to win nine matches in the single edition of a tournament.)